# Optimization of foreach statement, create new mapped Viewmodel list

Tags: optimization, foreach, lambda, viewmodel

Can someone please have a look at my code, I think there must be a way to optimize the foreach piece of code?

I have a database with `Artists`, each artist has multiple songTitles (called `Titles`), and each Title can have multiple `Meanings`.

```
Artist [1..*] Title [1..*] Meaning [0..*]
```

I want to find the count of `Meanings`, per `Title`, for an `Artist`, and return it as a new ViewModel List.

```
public class TitleVM
{
        public int TitleID { get; set; }
        public int MeaningCount { get; set; }
}


public List<TitleVM> GetTitlesByArtistID(int artistID)
{
        //find the artist by ID
        var titles = context.Titles.Where(x => x.ArtistID == artistID);

        //create new VMList to be returned
        var titleVMList = new List<TitleVM>();

        //loop through each title, 
        foreach (var item in titles)
        {
            //find the number of meanings,
            var count = 0;
            if (item.Meanings != null && item.Meanings.Count > 0)
            {
                count = item.Meanings.Count();
            }

            // and map it to VM,  add to list
            titleVMList.Add(new TitleVM
            {
                TitleID = TitleID,
                MeaningCount = count
            });
        }
        return titleVMList;
}
```

I thought mapping it would be easiest, but have no idea how to map a viewmodel with lists in this way.
In my project I use Omu.ValueInjecter for mapping basic models, because Automapper needs full trust to run, and my host doesn't allow it.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I read that its better to do an .AddRange then adding the the item with .Add each time.
I got my code down to the below:

```
 public int CountMeanings(IEnumerable<Meaning> meanings)
    {
        if (meanings != null && meanings.Count() > 0)
            return meanings.Count();
        return 0;
    }

    public List<TitleVM> GetTitlesByArtistID(int artistID)
    {
        var titleVMList = new List<TitleVM>();
        var titles = context.Titles.Where(x => x.ArtistID == artistID).AsEnumerable();
        titleVMList.AddRange(titles.Select(item => new TitleVM {
                               TitleID = item.TitleID,
                               MeaningCount = CountMeanings(item.Meanings)
                           }));
        return titleVMList;
    }
```